# Expression.Error: The name 'Number.from' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly

Tags: powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpF6w.png)

When I used this below query.

```
= List.Dates(
    Source,
    Number.from(DateTime.LocalNow()) - Number.From(Source),
    #duration(1,0,0,0)
)
```

It displays error as below:

> Expression.Error: The name 'Number.from' wasn't recognized.  Make sure
> it's spelled correctly.

Please help to provide a solution with the above error. Thanks.

Comment: You have a typo., Instead of **Number.from** you should write **Number.From**. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-from)

Answer (score 0):

So try `Number.From` instead of `Number.from` in the first instance.